# Python: Error message parsing

Tags: python, exception, python-2.7

I'm trying to handle IOError generated when trying to open a non existent file. I do:

```
try:
    inputFile = open('nosuchfile', 'r')
except IOError as exception:
    print 'error: %s' % (exception)
```

This gives me:

```
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nosuchfile'
```

But I'm only interested in the message and not the [Errno 2] part. So I change my code.

```
print 'error: %s' % (exception.strerror)
```

But now I get:

```
error: No such file or directory
```

Where did the name of the file go? I know I could just print the file name separately, but I would really like how (if at all) the name was stored in the exception, but not in either of its arguments (printing exception.errno gives 2).

I am using version 2.7.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The filename is stored in, well, the `filename` property:

```
try:
    inputFile = open('nosuchfile', 'r')
except IOError as exception:
    print ('error: %s: %r' % (exception.strerror, exception.filename))
```

Comment: Oh got it. But why is this not revealed when I print exception.args?

Comment: NB: `exception.strerror` is _not_ an Exception attribute

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D Well, [it does work](http://ideone.com/fyrrFv), so why do you think it wouldn't be an attribute?

Comment: It is an `IOError` attribute - not an `Exception` attribute - apparently one must call `str(exception)`

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D `str(exception)` is the whole message including the filename, which is not being asked for. `strerror` is just the core error string. And of course `strerror` and `filename` are only available in `IOError` exception objects. But that's not a problem here, since we only catch `IOError` in the first place.

Comment: Yes thanks - this comes up when searching for the exception messages in python and I tried calling `e.strerror` in an arbitrary exception - it's just a note for the passer-by