# How to parse URL from Python3 Requests Exception

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, timeoutexception

I am using Python3 requests module, doing a try/except and catching a timeout error specifically. The except statement returns the exception as a class object.  How can I parse out particular elements of the error, for example, the URL?  This is Python 3.7.8 on Ubuntu 18.04 if that matters.

```
try:
    result = requests.get(domain, timeout=5)
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as Err:
    print(type(Err))
    print(Err)
```

Returns --

```
<class 'requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout'>
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='10.10.10.92', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /custom.php (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7c16f14f73d1>, 'Connection to 10.10.10.92 timed out. (connect timeout=5)'))
```

I'd like to be able to grab just the "Max retries exceeded with url: /custom.php"  section.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Error message parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664190/python-error-message-parsing)

Comment: Not really, though it did give me something to look at that I had missed.  I guess I could turn the whole thing into a string then use substring operations to extract the part I wanted.  I might give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

`Timeout` inherits from `RequestException`, which has a `request` property. So you don't have to parse anything, the url is available via (in your example) `Err.request.url`. The request is of type [requests.Request](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Request).